# TypeFace of spannable EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, typeface

Does anybody know how to get the TypeFace of a spannable from EditText.

I have an EditText:

```
    // Instantiate EditText noteContent//
    noteContent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteContent);
   noteContent.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.NORMAL));
```

I have a spannable:

```
    if (id == R.id.italic) {

        int startSelection = noteContent.getSelectionStart();
        int endSelection = noteContent.getSelectionEnd();
        Spannable spannable = noteContent.getText();

        Typeface style = noteContent.getTypeface();

        if (style.equals(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.ITALIC))) {

            spannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), startSelection, endSelection , 0);

        } else {

            StyleSpanRemover spanRemover = new StyleSpanRemover();

            spanRemover.RemoveStyle(spannable, startSelection, endSelection, Typeface.ITALIC);
        }
    }
```

The problem is this if statment gets the typeface of the whole edittext not just the spannable. How do I get the current typeface for a spannable?

Comment: what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: To toggle on and off italic using an if statement and a menu item button R.id.italic @pskink

Comment: so call `noteContent.setTypeface` again either with italic or normal typeface

Comment: The problem with that is it does the entire text written in the EditText box. not just the part highlighted in the spannable. I want only the spannable to become Italisized @pskink

Comment: so use `spannable.setSpan` with `StyleSpan` doesn't it work?

Comment: yes, but the if statement is trying to find the Typeface of the EditText not the spannable. I don't know how to get the Typeface of a spannable to put in an if statement, do you? @pskink

Comment: use `Spanned#getSpans(int start, int end, Class<T> type)` to get all the spans of given type in the specified range

Comment: Ok cool, how do I put that code into an if statment to get the Typeface of the span @pskink